# Customizing the edit page title in ActiveAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, page-title, activeadmin

I am trying to change the page title to be the name of the item you are actually editing when you are on the edit page. I read in the active admin docs that you should use @page_title. The problem is I don't know where to put this for it to work for the edit page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Active Admin: How to set page title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905616/active-admin-how-to-set-page-title)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I posted this in the active admin google group and they are looking to add this ability in to the next update. If they end up adding it i will post some info here on how it is accomplished.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

```
controller do
  def new
    @page_title = 'new title'
    super
  end

  def edit
    @page_title = 'edit title'
    super
  end
end
```