# Active Admin: How to set page title?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

This seems like it should be relatively simple, but I've had some trouble tracking down the answer:

How do you set the page title in ActiveAdmin?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Consolidating answers and adding a little:

Most of this is on [this page on the wiki](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Set-page-title) (or I'll put it there soon).

Within the file that registers your model for activeadmin (e.g. app/admin/user.rb), you can have

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # a simple string
  index :title => "Here's a list of users" do
    ...
  end

  # using a method called on the instance of the model
  show :title => :name do
    ...
  end

  # more flexibly using information from the model instance
  show :title => proc {|user| "Details for "+user.name } do
    ...
  end

  # for new, edit, and delete you have to do it differently
  controller do
    def edit
      # use resource.some_method to access information about what you're editing
      @page_title = "Hey, edit this user called "+resource.name
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 10):

After searching got it,

You can add :title attribute to blocks of active admin.

e.g

1) To set title for index page,

```
index :title => 'Your_page_name' do
....
end
```

2) To set title for show page,

```
show :title => 'Your_page_name' do
....
end
```

Comment: for more details checkout: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/wiki/Set-page-title

Answer (score 5):

As per [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/activeadmin/hX8bWXfLgCQ), you can use a line like the following in the action of choice:

```
@page_title="My Custom Title"
```

For example, to implement this in a pre-existing action like 'new', you would do something like this:

```
controller do
  def new do
    @page_title="My Custom Title"
    new! do |format|
       format.html{render "my_new"}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Method definition with a block `def new do` Are you sure ?

Answer (score 4):

In case someone (like me) still struggles with action `new`:

```
def new
  @page_title="My Custom Title"
  super
end
```

Dont forget to add `super`. However, `edit` action doesnt need that.

Answer (score 4):

if I got your question right, you want to rename a model in activeadmin to appear with another name in all actions, for example renaming "Post" model to appear "Article" in ActiveAdmin, to do so just go to the model file inside Admin folder and the first line change from

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
```

to

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post, as: "Article"
```

and if something went wrong then restart your rails server, docker or whatever it is

Answer (score 2):

My example:

### two models and their association :

```rb
class Course < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :lessons, dependent: :destroy
end
class Lesson < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :course
end
```

I want to show the course title in its lessons index page, I tested two ways to do that.

### just for index

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Lesson do
  belongs_to :course, optional: true
  permit_params :title
  controller do
    def index
      @page_title = " #{Course.find(params[:course_id]).try(:title)}"
      super
    end
end
```

### or for all actions

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Lesson do
  belongs_to :course, optional: true
  permit_params :title
  controller do
    before_action {  
      @page_title = " #{Course.find(params[:course_id]).try(:title)}"
    }
  end
end
```

then you can use the @page_title

```rb
  index :title=> @page_title  do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column :title
    actions

  end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `ActiveAdmin.register_page` and want to set the menu name and page name at the top, try the following:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "ReleaseNotes" do
  menu label: "Release Notes"
  
  content title: "Release Notes" do
    render partial: 'index'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply do

```
index title: "Me new title"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to also leverage the controller action to give more granularity to changing the page title.  Especially when leveraging I18n with the `before_action` like @dayudodo did in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60612702/7573223).

## I18n approach

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    before_action :page_title

    # other controller stuff...

    def page_title
      @page_title = I18n.t(params[:action], scope: "active_admin.resources.user.page_title")
    end

    # other controller stuff...
  end
end
```

I have copied the [active_admin yml](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml) locally as suggested by ActiveAdmin's [documentation](https://activeadmin.info/1-general-configuration.html#internationalization-i18n) so that I can modify it for customization

```yaml
en:
  # other yaml stuff...

  active_admin:
    # more active_admin yaml stuff...

    resources: # added this key for organizing the customization
      # more resources...
      
      user:
        page_title:
          index: Custom Index Title
          new: Custom New Title

  # other yaml stuff...
```

with this you can still leverage injected variables with I18n, assuming you have method in your controller to like:

```rb
  def user
    @user ||= User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def page_title
    @page_title = I18n.t(params[:action], scope: "active_admin.resources.user.page_title", name: user.name)
  end
```

```yaml
  user:
    page_title:
      index: Custom Index Title
      new: Custom New Title
      show: "%{name}'s Details"
      edit: "Edit %{name}'s Details"
```

## without I18n

constants in ActiveAdmin blocks violate Ruby Style guides and will throw linter errors: [Defining Constants within a Block](https://rubystyle.guide/#no-constant-definition-in-block).  So we can [memoize](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/4-simple-memoization-patterns-in-ruby-and-one-gem/) instead

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  controller do
    before_action :page_title

    # other controller stuff...

    def action
      params[:action].to_sym
    end

    def page_title
      @page_title = page_titles_per_action[action]
    end

    def page_titles_per_action
      @page_titles_per_action ||= { index: "Custom Index Title", new: "Custom New Title" }
    end

    # other controller stuff...
  end
end
```